# Show Exception Message in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Created A Custom Exception Handler ... But It only Show Fix Status Text ..i want to show real exception message on Error View which occur in my Class ..

```
public class CustomExceptionHandlerFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            var msg = filterContext.Exception.Message;
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "Exception"
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `filterContext.Exception.StackTrace;` ?

```
public class CustomExceptionHandlerFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        //Your Code
        //var msg = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        //filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
        //{
        //    ViewName = "Exception"
        //};

        //My example
        var msg = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace;
        ViewResult viewResult = new ViewResult();
        viewResult.ViewName = "Exception";
        viewResult.ViewData.Add("CatchErrorStackTrace", msg);

        //create new controller and view for showing error message.
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Exception";

        filterContext.Result = viewResult;
    }
}
```

~/Error/Exception.cshtml

```
<div>@(ViewData["CatchErrorStackTrace"] == null ? string.Empty : ViewData["CatchErrorStackTrace"])</div>
```